# GridPane background not showing transparancy with image

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

This is the CSS for a 1x1 GridPane:

```
.equipInventory{
    -fx-border-image-source: url("../images/goldbg.png");
    -fx-border-image-width: 3px;
    -fx-border-image-slice: 90, 90;
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/fishingPole.png");
    -fx-background-size: 40px;
}
```

That results in:

[image]

The problem here is the .png should be at .2 transparency, as that's what I've set it at in photoShop. For some reason it's displaying at full opacity? Anyone know why this is behaving like this?

Comment: I fixed it - turns out it was working as intended but Scene Builder had cached the first attempt which was full opacity so wasn't refreshing. Shutting it down and back up fixed it. How silly.